# Using closures in modules to create private variables

Tags: javascript

I'm reading [the tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html#creating-a-dispatcher) on `Flux` and there is the following piece of code there:

```
var _callbacks = [];
var _promises = [];

var Dispatcher = function() {};
Dispatcher.prototype = assign({}, Dispatcher.prototype, {

  /**
   * Register a Store's callback so that it may be invoked by an action.
   * @param {function} callback The callback to be registered.
   * @return {number} The index of the callback within the _callbacks array.
   */
  register: function(callback) {
    _callbacks.push(callback);
    return _callbacks.length - 1; // index
  },
```

I'm curions about them using closure to make `_callbacks` variable private. But isn't this variable shared by all instances of `Dispatcher`?

Comment: Unless the whole code posted is inside a function, they don't make `_callbacks` private. I assume the tutorial assumes the code is inside a *module*. That's conceptually something else though.

Comment: I assume this whole code is inside a function - some kind of a module.

Comment: What is maybe less clear from the tutorial is that Dispatcher is supposed to be a singleton. There is only one instance the Dispatcher in the app at runtime, hence there is no problem "sharing" `_callbacks`. Look at `AppDispatcher`, it's kind of an (and the only) instance of `Dispatcher`, even if it wasn't created with `new`. If multiple independent instances should be created, the code as is would not work (I guess that's your concern).

Comment: @FelixKling, yes, but there will be many other dispatchers created similiar to `AppDispatcher`, that will share the same `Dispatcher` prototype.

Comment: *"yes, but there will be many other dispatchers created similiar"* Where? Not in the tutorial. As I said, according to the flux pattern there is only supposed to be a single dispatcher in an app. https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html#a-single-dispatcher

Comment: thanks, I'm wondering then why they are creating first `Dispatcher` and then extend it into `AppDispatcher` if `AppDispatcher` is the only one using `Dispatcher`? Why not create only `AppDispatcher`?

Answer (score 0):

It is. But **No one** can access the `_callbacks` variable directly. It's hidden by the register function.

Comment: Uhm, no? How does `register` "hide" `_callbacks`?

Comment: If I create two instances of `dispatcher`, and then register one callback for one, and  another callback for another, they both will have two  callbacks